# Feistel Cipher in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm trying to implement a Feistel Cipher, I have the following code:

```
public static byte[] Encode(byte[] bytes) {
        byte[] s = (byte[])bytes.Clone();
        int half = s.Length / 2;
        if (s.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new Exception("Unbalanced code");
        byte[] left = new byte[half];
        byte[] right = new byte[half];
        Array.Copy(s, left, half);
        Array.Copy(s, half, right, 0, half);

        for (var k = 0; k < ROUNDS; k++) {
            left = XOR(left,f(right));
            var temp = left; left = right; right = temp;
        }


        byte[] toReturn = new byte[s.Length];
        Array.Copy(left, 0, toReturn, half, half);
        Array.Copy(right, 0, toReturn, 0, half);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

In this sample, `ROUNDS` is 21 and f is a function that rearranges the bytes in an array of bytes.

Unfortunately, while bytes should be equal to Encode(Encode(bytes)), it's not. And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Any advice?

Edit:  The code for f()

```
public static byte[] f(byte[] s) {
        byte[] toReturn = (byte[])s.Clone();
        byte temp = s[0];
        for (var k = 1; k < s.Length; k++) {
            s[k-1] = s[k];
            s[k - 1] = (byte)(s[k - 1] ^ 45);
        }
        s[s.Length - 1] = temp;
        s[s.Length - 1] = (byte)(s[s.Length - 1] ^ 45);
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `f` as well?

Comment: Added the code for f

Comment: `f` mutates `s` instead of `toReturn`.

Comment: I also want to note that your cipher is *extremely* weak. About as strong as Caesar encryption.

Comment: This is not, strictly, a Feistel cipher.  You do not have a key, and you do not have round keys.  In a true Feistel cipher, the encryption and decryption operations differ and need different methods.  Try writing an explicit decrypt method, that shuld help you find any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodesInChaos is correct, the problem was the variable being mutated.